# What are basic concepts of fusion kitchen?

Tags: fusion

Are there any formal(izable) rules, or methods, or basic concepts in fusion kitchen cooking?

Comment: Would: "No, there are not." be acceptable as answer?

Comment: @PieterB you can try but I think that the other answers gives already a couple of good ideas what these concepts could be.

Comment: Keep the deuterium and tritium in sealed containers until you're ready to use them, oh, and ensure your apron gives you adequate protection against stray neutron splashes...

Answer (score 20):

Fusion cuisine probably dates back centuries, as people and products migrated and influenced one another. Consider the development and spread of the noodle, for example.  However the term "fusion" cuisine was probably applied in the 1970s in France and, slightly later, in America.  The idea is simple.  Ingredients and/or techniques from different cuisines are combined to create something new.  In its best form, the result is unique, surprising, and delicious.  However, critics, especially when the combination doesn't work, have sometimes dubbed it "confusion cuisine."

It would be difficult, at best, to define any sort of rules or basic concepts.  Remember, the very idea of fusion cuisine is to break the rules or basic concepts of a single cuisine, by combining differing rules and concepts of two or more different cuisines.  I guess the only concept I can come up with is that the dish has to make sense from a flavor, texture, and visual perspective.  In other words, to be successful it must be appealing and delicious.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are not- as Pieter suggested, is the answer here.

The reason for this is simple,

> [Food Fusion is a form of cooking that combines [*any*] contrasting culinary traditions or techniques into a single dish](https://www.nisbets.co.uk/what-is-food-fusion).

The basic concepts of cooking would obviously still apply, but it would be impossible to identify basic concepts of *fusion* cooking outside of these as there are so many variations.

As mentioned in the comments, one way you could look at is:

> "The only rule of fusion is that it follows the definition of fusion"

Comment: Your TL;DR is "there are no rules", but from the link you provide there seems to be at least one key rule — contrast. 

For example, a "full Irish breakfast" has black and white pudding; a "full English breakfast" has fried bread and a "full Scottish breakfast" has a tattie scone, but if you had all three items you still probably wouldn't call it "fusion" as the base meals are _too_ similar in style & preparation already. (I think "No there aren't" and "Contrast is a rule" are both fine answers, but should probably be separate answers.)

Comment: I really doubt anyone would not consider 3 British dishes to be "fusion" in any sense of the word though? @anotherdave

Comment: I also don't think the definition of the word can be a rule. That's like saying "The only rule of fusion is that it follows the definition of fusion"

Comment: The usage of potatoes by Europeans is already a kind of fusion cooking, but not seen as such.

Comment: @bee fair point! I was coming at it from the other angle (assuming the OP knows nothing about fusion food) so was thinking that the explication was the most important rule. Just said I'd add my alt POV.

Comment: @anotherdave I have amended the definition to the link I provided and just added my comment for clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

In current day the term "fusion cooking" is popularized by chefs with non-French background and a traditional French cooking education.

They are schooled in France and take that experience and mix that with dishes from their heritage to create new dishes.

A notable chef to do that is [David Chang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Chang)

Comment: Chang attended the French Culinary Institute in New York, and worked at Cafe Boulud, a French restaurant, also in New York.  These seem to be his primary education in French cuisine, in addition to his various other experiences with other cuisines.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen and moscafj, Thanks for the extra info, I watch a lot of show featuring Chang and was under the impression his French schooling was done in France.